# Problema de cache com o ajax(arquivos de texto)

Tags: php, ajax

Fiz a conexão ajax para introduzir um arquivo .txt em uma div, porém modifiquei o texto e salvei mas o texto não é alterado(como se eu não tivesse salvado)

Se quiser ver o site que está o texto(biologia->Cadeia Alimentar): http://estudos.epizy.com/

O "f12" da página: https://prnt.sc/libg1i
O que ta salvo(esquerda) e o que aparece(direita):https://prnt.sc/lic93o

```
<script>
function corpo(titulo, texto) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML = titulo;
        document.getElementById("corpo").innerHTML =
        this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", texto, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é cache. Tente fazer o seguinte.

Na linha.

```js
xhttp.open("GET", texto, true);
```

Troque por:

```js
xhttp.open("GET", texto + '?_now_=' + ((new Date()).getTime()), true);
```

Adicionar o tempo atual na requisição, faz com que toda requisição seja uma nova para o navegador e então o cache é ignorado.

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado ^-^) Não sabia que no ajax também tinha problema de cache